# Can I "star" or otherwise select issues in Redmine for reporting?

Tags: redmine

I've been asked to "list all the issues [in Redmine] that were outside the original spec, and give a report of time spent on those issues"

I have a large list of issues, about half of which were outside the original spec.  I'd like to go through the list and be able to "star" (like in a webmail client) certain issues, and then run a report of time spent on those issues.

Do you know of a plugin or an existing way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do it (second try), not very clean solution but a solution at least.

First of all you need to create a boolean custom field named *Send to report* (or what you want).

In the **issues view** select all the issues that you want to watch, then right click on the selected issues list and the **contextual menu** is displayed, change the value of *Send to report* to Yes.

Go to **Overview tab**, then select in the **Spent time** section the link **Report**, filter by the custom field *Send to report*.

It's not a clean solution because changing a custom field in order to report something will cause issues historial changes (+ email sending).

In any case, I hope it helps :)

Comment: First answer missunderstod the question, I hope second try fit it.